# Internet Explorer 11 not working with HTTPS (Let's Encrypt)

Tags: ssl, https, lets-encrypt, internet-explorer

I had an application that was running with HTTP in all the browsers with no problem. Then I configured an Let's Encrypt SSL certificate using win-acme v1.9.10.1. Find the link below:
https://github.com/PKISharp/win-acme/releases/tag/v1.9.10.1

After installing the certificate, I was able to run my application with HTTPS on all browsers ( Chrome, Firefox and Microsoft Edge) expect IE 11.

This is what's displayed when I try to run my application on IE 11:

[image: screenshot]

What could be causing this issue? Is IE 11 supported by Let's Encrypt? Thanks.

PS: The content above my DOCTYPE tag isn't part of my code.

Comment: Hi, does you got a certificate error in IE11 (red warning or such) ? as I think it's an application error more with the backend more than a lets's encrypt's error

Comment: I don't have any certificate error in IE11. Here's an article from Microsoft Support: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/3151631/rc4-cipher-is-no-longer-supported-in-internet-explorer-11-or-microsoft#easy but since it's working on Microsoft Edge, it doesn't explain why it's not working on IE 11. I also don't think that it's a Let's Encrypt error,but I'm not able to say what could be causing the issue. @yagmoth555

Comment: Do a simple test, put a static web page (.html) and naviguate to it in IE 11, if ok and no error, then I would check the app if you can debug what it send. At this point I'am not a dev, but maybe add logging to file to trace back where the apps fail to send the content

Answer (score 2):

***Is IE 11 supported by Let's Encrypt?***
Support depends more on the operating system than the browser. If you are using latest version of Windows everything should be fine:
https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/which-browsers-and-operating-systems-support-lets-encrypt/4394

I suggest you to make full validation of configuration and find anything suspicious:
https://github.com/PKISharp/win-acme/wiki/Validation-issues

Standard things to check on the browser side:

- Do other sites with the Let's Encrypt certificate work in IE11?
- Does the website work on other computers with IE11?